# Data Matrix Reader SDK for iOS

Tags: sdk

I have did some research on the data matrix reader but seem like there is not many free SDK can be used. Beside Zxing does any suitable sdk can be used for Ios development?

Answer (score 3):

The datamatrix format is now supported by iOS 8.  See `AVMetadataObjectTypeDataMatrixCode`

Here's some quick code to use it.

```
AVCaptureSession* captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
dispatch_queue_t metadataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.dataMatrixQueue", NULL);

metadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[metadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:metadataQueue];
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeDataMatrixCode];
//Add the output to the session
[captureSession beginConfiguration];
[captureSession addOutput:self.metadataOutput];
[captureSession commitConfiguration];
```

Then go implement the `captureSession:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection` delegate method

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS 7 you can now use the iOS SDK to create your own custom QR Reader, without any need of third party libraries.

Here you can find a great tutorial: http://nshipster.com/ios7/

or you can try this free repo with more detail example for reading multiple types of codes:
https://github.com/jpwidmer/iOS7-BarcodeScanner

Comment: Data matrix barcode format is not supported by iOS 7. From the 2D barcodes only QR, Aztec and PDF417 are supported.